# Get MSI log for Active Setup

Tags: log-files, windows-installer, diagnostic

One of my users has Outlook unable to start with *"Cannot start Microsoft Office Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook Window"* and [I've already ruled out existing add-ins.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-can-t-start-microsoft-outlook-or-receive-the-error-cannot-start-microsoft-office-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85) <sub>(This is just for background information and is not a part of the question proper.)</sub>

When it's starting, a Windows Installer window appears for a few seconds before the error, and Application Event Log has an entry that suggests that an Active Setup session fails:
<sub>(excerpt; translated, so may not exactly correspond to what an English Windows would write):</sub>

```
Log name:    Application
Source:      MsiInstaller
Event Code:   1033
Description:
Windows Installer has finished installing the product. Product name: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010. Version: 14.0.4763.1000. Language: 0. Vendor: Microsoft Corporation. Installation finished with status: 1635.
```

So, the question is:

**How do I get the `msiexec` log for this installation to find out what specifically is wrong?**

When I run a regular installation, I can just supply the `/log <file>` parameter. But this time, it's not a normal package installation, and it runs automagically so I can't change the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force Windows Installer to create a log for every installation session with registry settings as per [How to enable Windows Installer logging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer
Type: Reg_SZ
Value: Logging
Data: voicewarmupx
```

(the value is but a set of letter flags that can be in any order)

This will create a file `MSI*.log` in `%TEMP%` for each MSI's session.

Make sure to delete the value once you're done since these logs take up a lot of space!